# Need to change socket.io class to singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, singleton

What is the best way to make socket.io to a singleton? here i have three files i need to use socket.io method in **user.mjs**

## socket.mjs

```
class socketBusiness extends baseBusiness {
  //io = null;
  //connectedUsers = {}
  constructor(io) {
    super(io);
    this.io = io;
    this.connectedUsers = {};
    this.addUserRef= {}; 
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  bindEvents() {
    this.io.on("connection", this.onConnection);

    this.io.use(this.onBeginConnection);
  }
  unBindEvents() {
    this.io.off("connection", this.onConnection);
  }

  onConnection(socket) {
    let _io = this.io;
    let socketId = socket.id;


    socket.on("disconnect", reason => {
    });

    socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
    });
  }
 addUserRef(userId, cstId) {

      let arr = this.addUserRef[cstId] || [];
      if (arr.indexOf(cstId) < 0) {
        arr.push(cstId);
      }
      this.addUserRef[userId] = arr; 
  }
}
export default socketBusiness;
```

## user.mjs

```
const socket = require("socket.mjs)
export async function addCst(req, res) {
socket.addUserRef(req.id,req.cstId)
}
```

How i can access the socket.io method ? any help will be highly appreciated

## www.mjs

```
import socket from '../socket.mjs';


var server = createServer(app);
var io = new SocketServer(server, {})
var sb = new socketBusiness(io);
```

Comment: you are importing with `socket` `import socket from '../socket.mjs';` and creating the object using `socketBusiness` `var sb = new socketBusiness(io);`. it should be `new socket(io)`

Comment: Import is not an issue, I am just showing my problem example here might be there is some typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export an instance:

```
 export default new socketBusiness;
```

If you export a singleton, you can't pass io in the constructor. Move the initialization logic to a method:

```
constructor() { }

init(io) {
  this.io = io;
  this.bindEvents();
}
```

Then, initialize the singleton when you got the socket:

```
var io = new SocketServer(server, {})
socket.init(io);
```

Comment: Getting this error when i am using new keyword  "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

Comment: `export default new socketBusiness()` you missed the braces

Comment: @AZ_ those are optional.

Comment: @AbtisamAhmed right, cause `io` wasn't passed into the constructor.

Comment: @JonasWilms can we have any way to make socket.io multithreading?

Comment: Sure, run multiple NodeJS processes that share the sockets using Redis. Then ut can eben be multi server